# Apache rewrite condition for ajax crawling to pages with anchors

Tags: ajax, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an AngularJS app on an Apache webserver that I would like to have indexed by search engines (i.e. Google/Bing bots etc.). I have a PhantomJS script to crawl and take snapshots of pages on my site, and I have followed [the instructions from Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) on how to redirect any http://mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=* requests to the appropriate pages.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a few routes in the app that change content based on the anchor, e.g. http://mysite.com/#!/about is different from http://mysite.com/#!/about#overview. I would like these changes to be indexed, but the hash character '#' is used for commenting and even escaping it with a backslash doesn't work. I have consulted other SO answers (e.g. [Apache rewrite condition for ajax crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180626/apache-rewrite-condition-for-ajax-crawling) and [mod_rewrite page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466771/mod-rewrite-page-anchor)), but I have not found instructions on how to deal with anchors.

I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to redirect URLs using mod_rewrite to snapshots that include anchors? For example, using the escaped version of '#' ('%23'):

   ```
   http://mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about%23overview => http://mysite.com/snapshots/about#overview.html
   ```

   Here's what I currently have in my .htaccess file, though it does not work for pages with anchors:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On                                                                
   Options +FollowSymLinks                                                         

   # Route for the index page
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/$                              
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/index.html [NC,L]  

   # All other routes                                
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$                         
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/%1.html [NC,L]
   ```
2. If (1) is not allowed, my idea on how to solve this problem is replace all '#' with '.' in the file names of the snapshots. Then I would need a mod_rewrite rule that would replace '#' with '.' in the escaped_fragment query parameter. Going back to my example, I currently have a rule that would take /?_escaped_fragment_=about#overview and reroute it to /snapshots/about.overview.html.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/about%23overview$              
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/about.overview.html [NE,NC,L]
   ```

   Is there a simple general rule I could use to implement this type of routing?

Any other ideas for how to solve this problem with general rewrite conditions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /snapshots/%1.html? [R,NE,L]
```

It redirects `/?_escaped_fragment_=about%23overview` to `/snapshots/about%23overview.html`

Comment: I tried this on my browser and it appended the absolute path to the snapshots directory into the request: e.g. http://mysite.com/var/www/html/snapshots/about%23overview.html. If I remove the redirect R flag, though, it works. I then tried "Fetching as Google," and got a 404 not found. If I put the redirect back in, it works for Google though. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say `I then tried "Fetching as Google` what was your original URL that you tried?

Comment: I thought original URL is something like `http://mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=...`

Comment: Ah yes, but the [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en) tool let's you instruct a Google bot to visit your page as if it was indexing it. Thus the Google bot will transform the request into `http://mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=...`. The 404 not found error says `/snapshots//about%23overview.html` was not found on the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38635/discussion-between-mtitan8-and-anubhava)

Comment: Fetch as Google does NOT work as the actual crawler does for reading fragments of Angular apps. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/2Gs_eGQVw_k